# python index of max change code not working

Tags: python, exploratory-data-analysis

I have been doing a project from Stratascratch and the code in their solution doesn't work. I want to know what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
# get the index of max change to answer what date did it occur
print(daily_sales_df['difference_btw_prev_day'].idxmax(axis="columns"))
daily_sales_df[daily_sales_df.index == '2013-04-29']
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How do I convert everything into an int to add them together?

The output should be:
2013-04-29 00:00:00

sale_day    sale_amount prev_day_sale_amount  difference_btw_prev_day
2013-04-29  732         458.0                 274.0

Comment: The problem seems to come from your data. In the column `difference_btw_prev_day`, it looks like you have multiple data typed (`str` and `int`), so they can't be ordered with respect to one another

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first selecting 1 column: `daily_sales_df['difference_btw_prev_day']` and are then asking for the max across columns.

Instead, find the index of the (first) row that maximises this column by `daily_sales_df['difference_btw_prev_day'].idxmax()`.